# Draw circle from html input values

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
 drawCircle(150,150,100,'canvas');

 $('#radius').change(function(){
  $('#rVal').text($(this).val());
 });

 $('#x').change(function(){
  $('#xVal').text($(this).val());
 }); 

 $('#y').change(function(){
  $('#yVal').text($(this).val());
 });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z2EBh/ 
I'd like to know how I can redraw my circle each time when value in range input is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out here http://jsfiddle.net/Z2EBh/2/

You need to redraw the circle on every change. Then also make sure to clear it or else it gets overwritten like 20 times.

```
$('#x').change(function () {
    $('#xVal').text($(this).val());
    xVal = $(this).val();
    drawCircle(xVal, yVal, rVal, 'canvas');
});
```

I also made global variables for xVal, yVal, and rVal. So it keeps track of each slider.

Side note: http://jsfiddle.net/Z2EBh/1/  Made this on accident. Pretty cool illustrations that happen if you dont clear the canvas

Comment: Yeah, when you change radius it looks like vinyl. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The change Event in jquery would be a good start.

http://api.jquery.com/change/